# Call collection property with a variable in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to call a property within a collection using variables. I have multiple properties and I do not want to have to use a case statement just to get the information out. Here is the code sample

```
Sub Main()
    MessageBox("Total: " & GetNum("Total","1"))
    MessageBox("Night: " & GetNum("Night","1"))
End Sub

Private Function GetNum(ByVal pstrProp AS String, ByVal pstrNum AS String) As Double
    Dim lobjProperties as New Properties
    'this is where the issue is
    return lobjProperties."pstrProp"(pstrNum)
End Function

Public Class Properties
    Public ReadOnly Property Total(ByVal pstrNum As String) As Double
        Get
            Select Case pstrNum
                Case "1"
                    Return 48
                Case "2"
                    Return 30
                Case Else
                    Return 0
            End Select
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property Night(ByVal pstrNum As String) As Double
        Get
            Select Case pstrNum
                Case "1"
                    Return 9
                Case "2"
                    Return 9
                Case Else
                    Return 0
            End Select
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to determine which property to call at runtime, using reflection is your best bet, but the downside of going that route is you lose compile-time checking. What if the the code that decides which property to call misspells the property? Run-time error and crash.

You can also use a dictionary object in your `Properties` class. You might set up a dictionary object like this:

```
Private m_nightValues As New Dictionary(Of String, Double)
m_nightValues("1") = 9
m_nightValues("2") = 9
```

and in the `Night` property, say something like

```
Dim value As Double
If m_nightValues.TryGetValue(pstrNum, value) Then
    Return value
Else
    Return 0
End If
```

Fairly dynamic, while retaining syntax checking.